# can't get noUISlider to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, nouislider

I can't get noUISlider to work
Here my code snippet:

```js
<script>
var handlesSlider = document.getElementById('slidertest');

noUiSlider.create(handlesSlider, {
 start: [ 4000, 8000 ],
 range: {
  'min': [  2000 ],
  'max': [ 10000 ]
 }
});
</script>
```

```html
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>TEST</title>    
<link rel="stylesheet/less" type="text/css" href="css/style.less"/>
<link href="css/nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="scripts/less.js"> </script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"> </script>
<script src="scripts/jquery-ui.min.js"> </script>
<script src="scripts/dropzone.js"> </script>
<script src="scripts/nouislider.min.js"> </script>
</head>



...

<div id="slidertest"></div>
```

**And I'm getting this error:
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'nodeName' of null**

Comment: the error is related to what file exactly or what line ?

Comment: File: nouislider.min.js:3
and Line 3 is nearly the whole code, its too long to post it here :/

Comment: Try debugging with the non-minified versions.

Comment: okay i changed the min version to the uncompressed version and now the target line is: 
"if ( !target.nodeName ) {"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

try surrounding your javascript with :

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    var handlesSlider = document.getElementById('slidertest');

noUiSlider.create(handlesSlider, {
    start: [ 4000, 8000 ],
    range: {
        'min': [  2000 ],
        'max': [ 10000 ]
    }
});
});
```

Comment: the problem was that the javascript excuted before the html element is rendred so when u add $( document ).ready it will be excuted after the rendring is done of all html elements